# Should I use a HTML5 tag for my search?

Tags: html, search, semantics

Should I use a HTML5 specific tag for my search on my new site so I can remain semantically correct?
My site's structure is something like this

```
--------------------
      Header
--------------------
search   |   nav
--------------------
      article
--------------------
       footer
--------------------
```

This is my concern mostly because the search plays an important role on this page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
<input type="search">
```

Searching is a way of navigating a website, so you could just add it to the `<nav>` element.

In this case, the `<nav>` element could be a child element of the `<header>`, [just like the last example in the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-header-element).

```
<header>
  <h1>Site title</h1>
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search…">
  <nav>
    …
  </nav>
</header>
<article>
  <h1>Page title</h1>
</article>
<footer>
  …
</footer>
```

Comment: I read about this approach but I wasn't sure the <nav> would fit well in this picture.

Answer (score 0):

your structure should this (if you follow html5) :

```
<header>this is header</header>

<section>
    <section>
        <form>
          <input type="search">
        </form>
    </section>
    <nav>
        this is navigation
    </nav>
</section>

<main>
    <article>this content article</article>
    <aside>this sidebar</aside>
</main>


<footer>this is footer</footer>
```